# pandas.DataFrame.to_csv: selectively apply date_format by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

I have a dataframe with multiple columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2011-01-01 10:15:20', '2016-11-17 08:22:10'],
'text': ['red', 'purple'],
'datetime': ['2011-01-01 10:15:20', '2016-11-17 08:22:10']})
```

I want to export this `df` to a `csv` file using pandas' `.to_csv(...)` and save the column `date` in the format `%Y-%m-%d` but the column `datetime` in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` and can't find a way to modify the code accordingly.

I have tried

1. `df.to_csv('output.csv', date_format = '%Y-%m-%d')`, which transforms **all** columns' date format, including the column `datetime`, where I want to keep the time.
2. `df.to_csv('output.csv')` (without using `date_format = ...`) displays **all** columns' date format as date**time** - yet I want the column `date` to not carry the time-component.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?
Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think selective is not possible, [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#writing-to-csv-format):

> **date_format**: Format string for datetime objects

Solution is convert column to dates before `to_csv`:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date
print (df.to_csv())
```

Or:

```
print (df.assign(date=df['date'].dt.date).to_csv())

,date,text,datetime
0,2011-01-01,red,2011-01-01 10:15:20
1,2016-11-17,purple,2016-11-17 08:22:10
```